Dask adaptive deployment in azure kubernetes
I am trying to deploy a dask cluster with 0 workers and 1 scheduler, based on the work load need to scale up the worker to required, i found that the adaptive deployment is the correct way, i am using helm based deployment , but i couldn't find any proper docs regarding deployment via helm for dask adaptive deployment, or is there any other feature available to achive my requirements

Could you elaborate little bit more and share what all you have tried so far? if you need adaptive scaling you have https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-autoscaler?tabs=azure-cli and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/keda-about.

I am trying to implement https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/adaptive.html, in azure kubernets but i couldn't find a docs regarding the helm based approch

In order to deploy a Dask cluster with adaptive scaling on AKS using Helm to dynamically scale workers based on workload.
install dask
helm repo add dask https://helm.dask.org/
helm repo update
helm install dask-cluster dask/dask


Enable adaptive scaling by modifying the values.yaml file used by the Helm chart.
scheduler:
  replicas: 1
  env:
    - name: DASK_SCHEDULER__ADAPTIVE__ENABLED
      value: "true"  # Enable adaptive scaling
    - name: DASK_SCHEDULER__ADAPTIVE__INTERVAL
      value: "1s"  # Check scaling every second

worker:
  replicas: 0  
  autoScaler:
    enabled: true
    minReplicas: 0  
    maxReplicas: 10  
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: "1"
      memory: "2Gi"
    requests:
      cpu: "0.5"
      memory: "1Gi"

cluster:
  adaptive:
    enabled: true
    minimum: 0  
    maximum: 10  

helm upgrade --install dask-cluster dask/dask -f values.yaml


Verify Deployment and access dask dashboard
kubectl get pods
kubectl port-forward svc/dask-cluster-scheduler 8787:80



Connect to the Dask scheduler and submit a workload and test
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.array as da


client = Client("tcp://localhost:8786")

# Submit a workload
x = da.random.random((10000, 10000), chunks=(1000, 1000))
result = (x ** 2).sum().compute()
print("Result:", result)



